# Printing day of the week from exact date in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to print the day of the week of given date.
This command works pretty well:

```
TARGET=$(date -u -d'2015-10-25' '+%u')
```

But inside my bash script there is an error, what should be wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
day=25
month=10
year=2015
command1='date -u -d'
command3=''\'
command2=$year-$month-$day
fullcommand=$command1$command3$command2$command3' '$command3'+%u'$command3
echo $fullcommand
TARGET=$($fullcommand)
echo $TARGET
```

There is an error:

```
date: the argument ‘'+%u'’ lacks a leading '+';
```

Comment: put the echo first, then show what it prints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use so many temporary variables and **definitely escaping single quote inside another single quote won't work in shell**.

Simplify it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
day=25
month=10
year=2015
command1='date -u -d'
TARGET=$(date -u -d "$year-$month-$day" '+%u')
echo $TARGET
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash
day=25
month=10
year=2015
command1='date -u -d'
command3=''\'
command2=$year-$month-$day
fullcommand="$command1 $command2 +%u"
echo $fullcommand
TARGET=$($fullcommand)
echo $TARGET
```

I do not have the answer to why, though